# Plot a 3D surface described by equality

Tags: plotting

Is there an easy way to plot a 3D surface e.g. `z^2 = x^2 + y^2 -1` ? I tried `RegionPlot3D` but it seems it works only for surfaces described by inequalities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe [`ContourPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot3D.html) is what you are searching for:

```
ContourPlot3D[ z^2 == x^2 + y^2 - 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]
```

[image]